# Get/Export my app files from Google App Server

Tags: google-app-engine

I've applications on Google App Engine

I've lost all my data on hdd

Can I somehow get my applications from google server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A your-app-id app-dir
```

This function can be disabled in the Admin Console, but is enabled by default.

See [this document for more information](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code).